# How to integrate Azure Spring Cloud with Angular frontend

Tags: azure-aks, azure-spring-cloud

How to integrate backend apps from Azure Spring Cloud with some Angular frontend? Is AKS one solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are already running an AKS cluster, there are more time and cost-efficient ways to deploy an Angular front-end on Azure.

You can deploy static sites which are [hosted from a storage account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/static-websites-on-azure-storage-now-generally-available/?WT.mc_id=ng_deploy_azure-github-cxa). There is a tool called [ng-deploy](https://github.com/Azure/ng-deploy-azure) which streamlines the process.

If you prefer a container based approach, you can [create a container](https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-an-angular-app/) that runs nginx to serve your built Angular application and deploy it to Azure using [Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart) or [App Services](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/app-service)